# Craft as a gallery

Tags: assets, gallery

I started using Craft a while ago and it perfectly fits my needs. Now my website is growing pretty well, and i'm happy. But I also have an old photo gallery that I want to update.

I know that it's possible to do it with Craft. My question is will it support my gallery.

I have over 50'000 pictures of size between 500Ko and 1.5Mo with one thumbnail for each picture, organised between albums that are structured in a hierarchical tree.

**Will Craft be able to handle it ?** I currently use [gallery](http://galleryproject.org/), but it's getting slow, and got a problem with it and now half my gallery is broken. So I really want to move it inside my craft website, to easily manage website with it using the centralized system user.

In a more generic way of asking the question, **what's the maximum amount of assets Craft is able to handle ?**

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real higher limit on Craft itself on the amount of Assets, Entries, Tags, Categories (Elements) etc. that you can store. When reaching a higher limit of actual database entries it'll come down to your hardware and database setup.

Speaking to your specific problem 50,000 entries (Assets) are nothing. I'm guessing you might want to organize these in either a Structure or Channel (your "albums") and then relate Assets to these to get the same type of album gallery setup you currently are using.

There's been some discussions about "How much Craft can handle" and if you search a little deeper you can probably find those topics as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, we've seen installations with 300-400 thousand users/assets/etc.